Does PostgreSQL Replica Server Generate WAL Files?
My setup with PostgreSQL 14 streaming replication, includes pgBackRest for archiving to a dedicated repository server. Both archive commands and archive recovery work from this repository. Despite the setup with pgBackRest and a dedicated repository server, the replica server is generating its own WAL files. I expect the replica to apply WALs from the repository server as needed, not generate its own.

How do you know that your replica is generating WAL files?

Looking the pg_wal directory on the replica server inflating with new files being generated.

Are they definitely new files being generated by the replica, or are they copies from the master? If your replica is creating its own WALs, it is no longer a replica :/

I'm not sure about this, I never noticed it... To my understanding, it didn't generate WAL files on the replica... I only noticed with the increase in disk usage.

The standby does not generate WAL, it writes copies of the primary's WAL segments that get filled with the data streamed from the primary.
These WAL files serve two purposes:

they allow the standby to recover from a crash during recovery

they buffer WAL that has been received from the primary but cannot be replayed yet because of a replication conflict


If the WAL on the standby grows large, replay must be delayed. See this article for more details about replication conflicts.
